# React: Invalid hook call in SubmitForm, custom hook useSendFormData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I made a hook useSendFormData, when I use it, I get Invalid hook call.

Hook takes

- data from SubmitForm
- url:string,
- method: post or put
- success:
  success message if it was successful
- id: not required but if item has id
  i is added to api call.

Code:

```
     export const useSendFormData = async ({
              formData,
              url,
              method,
              success,
              id,
            }) => {
              const [data, setData] = useState({
                error: "",
                loading: true,
                success: "",
                data: [],
              });
              const setPartData = (partialData) => setData({ ...data, ...partialData });
              try {
                if (method === "post") {
                  const { data } = await axios.post(
                    `${SERVER_API}api/v1/${url}/${id ?? ""}`,
                    formData
                  );
                  setPartData({ data, success, error: null });
                } else if (method === "put") {
                  const { data } = await axios.post(
                    `${SERVER_API}api/v1/${url}/${id ?? ""}`,
                    formData
                  );
                  setPartData({ data, success, error: null });
                }
            
                setPartData({
                  loading: false,
                });
              } catch (err) {
                const { data } = err.response;
                setPartData({
                  error: data.error,
                  success: null,
                  loading: false,
                });
              }
              return {
                data,
              };
            };
```

I call it inside submit form, I don't know this matter but I use react-hook-forms for handling forms

```
    const sendFormData = useSendFormData

    const handleForm = async (info) => {
        const { data } = await sendFormData({
          formData: info,
          url: "auth/forgot-password",
          method: "post",
          success: "A password reset message has been sent to your email",
        });
    
        console.log(data);
    
        reset();
      };
```

If I change

```
const sendFormData = useSendFormData
```

to

```
const sendFormData = useSendFormData()
```

I get an error:

> Cannot destructure property 'formData' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

How can I make this work and if you see any way of improving this custom hook I would be very grateful for your help and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you designed your hook the fetch is done once the hook is invoked. Instead you should define a `sendFormData` function inside your hook and return it along with data state (or any other variables you need). Since you want `response.data` to be returned I adapted the function to return `response.data`:

```
export const useSendFormData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    error: "",
    loading: true,
    success: "",
    data: [],
  });

  const sendFormData = async ({
    formData,
    url,
    method,
    success,
    id,
  }) => {
    const setPartData = (partialData) => setData({ ...data, ...partialData });
    try {
      let response
      if (method === "post") {
        response = await axios.post(
          `${SERVER_API}api/v1/${url}/${id ?? ""}`,
          formData
        );
        setPartData({ data: response.data, success, error: null });
      } else if (method === "put") {
        response = await axios.post(
          `${SERVER_API}api/v1/${url}/${id ?? ""}`,
          formData
        );
        setPartData({ data: response.data, success, error: null });
      }
      setPartData({
        loading: false,
      });
      return response.data

    } catch (err) { 
      const { data } = err.response;
      setPartData({
        error: data.error,
        success: null,
        loading: false,
      });
      return data
    }
  }

  return {
    data, sendFormData
  };
};
```

With that you can call your hook properly at your component body, extracting `data` and `sedFormData`:

```
// here you have your data state and sendFormData extracted
const { data, sendFormData } = useSendFormData()


const handleForm = async (info) => {
  // here you have your response.data returned
  const data = await sendFormData({
    formData: info,
    url: "auth/forgot-password",
    method: "post",
    success: "A password reset message has been sent to your email",
  });

  console.log(data);

  reset();
};
```

Comment: but i want response from axios to set in setData useState hook isnt it possible ?

Comment: is it working now, or is therre any other issue?

Comment: i dont know why we cant only return data state only in sendFormData.

Comment: if you actually mean the function sendFormData, setPartData is async so you won't have the updated state just right away. you will get an outdated state value being returned if you return `data` from it instead of `response.data`.

Comment: if i will use it in useEffect it will work ? Retruning it only in sendFormData?

Comment: you better call your hook at your function body. you can extract `sendFormData` and use it inside `useEffect`.

Comment: also, if the answer provides clarification about your `original question` feel free to accepted as an answer :)